# Color a Specific character in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, colors

I am making a python Game Emulator to simulate Telnet logging in and Takeover and also reviewing the code with my group.

Problem is that I want this to look great, And I took inspiration BitchX And its design. So here is what I have as of right now (I snipped the code because the rest is unfinished and long)

```
from colored import fg, bg, attr
red = fg('red_1')
bloodred = fg('dark_red_2')
purple = fg('purple_1a')
white = fg('white')
green = fg('light_green')
blue = fg('blue')
grey = fg('grey_54')
yellow = fg('yellow')
reset = attr('reset')
os.system('clear')
print(purple,"""
                                ▒▒▒▒                       ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒
     ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒█▒               ▒▒▒█▒▒                     ▒▒▒▒▒██▌▒▒▒▒
   ▒▒▒▒▒█████▒▒▒▒▒▒          ▒▒▒████▒▒                   ▒▒▒▒█▒▒█▄ ▒▒▒▒
  ▒ ▒▒████▒█████▒▄▒         ▒▒███▒█▒██▒▒▒▒     ▒▄▒▒    ▒▒▒▐▒▒██████▄▒▒
  ▒▒▒███████▒▒████▒▒        ▒████▒▒█▒███ ▒   ▒▒▒██▒▒▒   ▒▒▐███▌▐████▌▒▒▒
▒▒▒▒▄▒▒██▀▀▀▀▀█▒███▒▒       ▒███▒▒▒▒▒▒███▒▒  ▒▒████▒▒▒   ▒▒███ ▒ ████ ▒▒▒
 ▒▒▐█▒█▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▀███▌▒▒      ▒█▌▌▒▒▄▄▒▒▐█▒▒▒ ▒▒██▀▒███▒▒   ▒███▒▒▒ ▒███▒▒▒▒
▒▒▒████▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒█▒▒▒      ▒███▒████▒███▒▒  ██▌▒▒▒███▒▒  ▒██▌▒▒▒▒▒████▒▒▒▒
▒ ▒███▒▒▒▒     ▒▒▒▒▒▒       ██▒██████▒▒██▒▒  ███▒▒▒▒██▒▒  ▒██▌▒▒▒▒▒ ███▄▒▒
▒ ▒█▒█▒▒▒                   ██▒▒██ ██▒███▒▒  ▐██ ▒▒▒███▒  ▒▐█▌▒▒▒▒▒ ▐████▒▒▒
▒▒▒███▒▒▒                  ▒███▒██ ██▒█▒█▒▒  ▄██▒▒▒▒▐███▒ ▒██▌▒▒▒▒▒▒▐█▄███▒▒
 ▒▒█▒█▌▒▒            ▒▒▒   ▒███▒██ ██▒▒██▒▒ ▐██▌▒▒▒▒▒███▒▒▒██▌▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒██▄██▒▒▒
  ▒███▒▒       ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒████▒▒███▒██ ██ ▒██▒▒  ██▌▒  ▒▒████▒▒██▌ ▒▒▒▒▒ ▒███████▒
  ▒██▒▒      ▒▒▒▒▒▒████▒███▒██▌▒██ ██▒▒██▒▒▒ ██▌▒   ▒▒███▒▒▐██ ▒▒▒█▒▒▒▒ ██▒██▌
  ▒███▒▒     ▒▒█████▒█▒▀▀██▒██ ███ ██▒▒██▒▒▒▒▐█▌▒ ▒█▌ ▐██▌▒▐██▌ ▒█▒█▒▒▒ █▌▒██▒
  ▒█▒█▌▒    ▒▒█▒█▒▒▀███▒▒▌▀███▒▒██ ██▒▒██▒▒▒▒██▌▒ ███▌▒██▌▒██▒▌ ▒██▀▒▒▒▄████▒▒
  ▒██▒█▒   ▒▒█▒█▒▒▒▒▒███▒▌▒▒██▒▒██  █▒▒██▒▒▒▒██▌▒ ███▌▒██▌▒███▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ █████▒▒▒
  ▒▒█▒█▒▒ ▒▒█▒█▒▒   ▒█▒█▒▌  ██▒▒█████▒▒█▐▒▒▐███▌▒ ▒█ ▒▒██▌▐███ ▒▒█▒▒ █████▒▒▒
  ▒▒████▒▒ ███▒▒    ▒███▒▌  ██▒▒ ████▒███▒▒▐███▌▒   ▒▒███▒▐██▌▒▒▒▒▒ ▐████▒▒
  ▒▒██▒██▒▒█▒▒▒   ▒▒████▒▌ ▒██▒▒▒██▌▒██▒▀▌▒▒███▌▒▒ ▒▒███▒▌▐██▌▒▒▒▒ ████▒▒▒
  ▒▒█▒███▒▒▀▒   ▒▒█████▌▒█ ▒▐█▒▒▒▒▒▒▒█▒█▒▌▒▒ ██▌▒▒▒▒▒███▒▌▒█▒▌▒▒▒ ▄███▒▒▒
  ▒▒███▒█▒▒▒▒  ▒▒██▒███▒▒▐ ▒▒███▒▒▒▒▄█▒█▒▌▒▒▒▐██▒▒▄▄██▌▒▒▌▒██▒▒▒▒████ ▒▒
  ▒▒█▒█████▄▒▒▒▒███▒██▒▒ ▐ ▒▐████▒▒█▒██▒▒▌▒▒▒███▒█████▒▒▒▌▒██ ▒ ████▌▒▒
  ▒▒▒▒██▒█▒███▄█████▒▒▌ ▒▐ ▒▐▐█████▒▒██▒▒▌▒▒▒▐██▐███▒ ▒▒ ▌▒█  █████▀▒▒
     ▒▒▒▀████▒███▌▒▒▒▌ ▒▐ ▒▐▒██▒█████▒▒▒▌ ▒▒▒█▌███▒▒▒  ▒▌▒███████▒
       ▒▒▒██▄████▒▒ ▒▌ ▒▐ ▒▐▒▒▒███▐▒▒▒▒ ▌ ▒▒█████▒▒▒   ▒▌██▐██▒▒▌▒
          █████     ▒▌ ▒▐█▒▐  ▒▒█▒▐▄▒▒  ▌ ▒▒████▌       ▒████▀▒▒▒▌▒
          ████▐     ▒▌     ▐█  ▒▒▒▒▐    █ ▒▒██▌▌      ▒▌ ▌▒▒▒▒▒▌
           ██ ▐▐█   ▒█             █      ▒▒██▌▌       ▌ ▌▒▒   █ """,reset)
print(white,"                     .:[",green,"/\"]Created By Antichrist [/\]:.")
print(white,"                            [+] Login Page [+]")
```

Here is what it looks like when ran in terminal:
[Image In Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Llpb8.png)

As you can see its all purple and that is what i don't want. i want '█' to be ***purple*** and '▒' To be ***bloodred***. If anyone has any answers that would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would propose to just replace each charakter with `color + charakter + reset` like this.

```
string = """
                                ▒▒▒▒                       ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒
     ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒█▒               ▒▒▒█▒▒                     ▒▒▒▒▒██▌▒▒▒▒
   ▒▒▒▒▒█████▒▒▒▒▒▒          ▒▒▒████▒▒                   ▒▒▒▒█▒▒█▄ ▒▒▒▒
  ▒ ▒▒████▒█████▒▄▒         ▒▒███▒█▒██▒▒▒▒     ▒▄▒▒    ▒▒▒▐▒▒██████▄▒▒
  ▒▒▒███████▒▒████▒▒        ▒████▒▒█▒███ ▒   ▒▒▒██▒▒▒   ▒▒▐███▌▐████▌▒▒▒
▒▒▒▒▄▒▒██▀▀▀▀▀█▒███▒▒       ▒███▒▒▒▒▒▒███▒▒  ▒▒████▒▒▒   ▒▒███ ▒ ████ ▒▒▒
 ▒▒▐█▒█▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▀███▌▒▒      ▒█▌▌▒▒▄▄▒▒▐█▒▒▒ ▒▒██▀▒███▒▒   ▒███▒▒▒ ▒███▒▒▒▒
▒▒▒████▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒█▒▒▒      ▒███▒████▒███▒▒  ██▌▒▒▒███▒▒  ▒██▌▒▒▒▒▒████▒▒▒▒
▒ ▒███▒▒▒▒     ▒▒▒▒▒▒       ██▒██████▒▒██▒▒  ███▒▒▒▒██▒▒  ▒██▌▒▒▒▒▒ ███▄▒▒
▒ ▒█▒█▒▒▒                   ██▒▒██ ██▒███▒▒  ▐██ ▒▒▒███▒  ▒▐█▌▒▒▒▒▒ ▐████▒▒▒
▒▒▒███▒▒▒                  ▒███▒██ ██▒█▒█▒▒  ▄██▒▒▒▒▐███▒ ▒██▌▒▒▒▒▒▒▐█▄███▒▒
 ▒▒█▒█▌▒▒            ▒▒▒   ▒███▒██ ██▒▒██▒▒ ▐██▌▒▒▒▒▒███▒▒▒██▌▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒██▄██▒▒▒
  ▒███▒▒       ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒████▒▒███▒██ ██ ▒██▒▒  ██▌▒  ▒▒████▒▒██▌ ▒▒▒▒▒ ▒███████▒
  ▒██▒▒      ▒▒▒▒▒▒████▒███▒██▌▒██ ██▒▒██▒▒▒ ██▌▒   ▒▒███▒▒▐██ ▒▒▒█▒▒▒▒ ██▒██▌
  ▒███▒▒     ▒▒█████▒█▒▀▀██▒██ ███ ██▒▒██▒▒▒▒▐█▌▒ ▒█▌ ▐██▌▒▐██▌ ▒█▒█▒▒▒ █▌▒██▒
  ▒█▒█▌▒    ▒▒█▒█▒▒▀███▒▒▌▀███▒▒██ ██▒▒██▒▒▒▒██▌▒ ███▌▒██▌▒██▒▌ ▒██▀▒▒▒▄████▒▒
  ▒██▒█▒   ▒▒█▒█▒▒▒▒▒███▒▌▒▒██▒▒██  █▒▒██▒▒▒▒██▌▒ ███▌▒██▌▒███▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ █████▒▒▒
  ▒▒█▒█▒▒ ▒▒█▒█▒▒   ▒█▒█▒▌  ██▒▒█████▒▒█▐▒▒▐███▌▒ ▒█ ▒▒██▌▐███ ▒▒█▒▒ █████▒▒▒
  ▒▒████▒▒ ███▒▒    ▒███▒▌  ██▒▒ ████▒███▒▒▐███▌▒   ▒▒███▒▐██▌▒▒▒▒▒ ▐████▒▒
  ▒▒██▒██▒▒█▒▒▒   ▒▒████▒▌ ▒██▒▒▒██▌▒██▒▀▌▒▒███▌▒▒ ▒▒███▒▌▐██▌▒▒▒▒ ████▒▒▒
  ▒▒█▒███▒▒▀▒   ▒▒█████▌▒█ ▒▐█▒▒▒▒▒▒▒█▒█▒▌▒▒ ██▌▒▒▒▒▒███▒▌▒█▒▌▒▒▒ ▄███▒▒▒
  ▒▒███▒█▒▒▒▒  ▒▒██▒███▒▒▐ ▒▒███▒▒▒▒▄█▒█▒▌▒▒▒▐██▒▒▄▄██▌▒▒▌▒██▒▒▒▒████ ▒▒
  ▒▒█▒█████▄▒▒▒▒███▒██▒▒ ▐ ▒▐████▒▒█▒██▒▒▌▒▒▒███▒█████▒▒▒▌▒██ ▒ ████▌▒▒
  ▒▒▒▒██▒█▒███▄█████▒▒▌ ▒▐ ▒▐▐█████▒▒██▒▒▌▒▒▒▐██▐███▒ ▒▒ ▌▒█  █████▀▒▒
     ▒▒▒▀████▒███▌▒▒▒▌ ▒▐ ▒▐▒██▒█████▒▒▒▌ ▒▒▒█▌███▒▒▒  ▒▌▒███████▒
       ▒▒▒██▄████▒▒ ▒▌ ▒▐ ▒▐▒▒▒███▐▒▒▒▒ ▌ ▒▒█████▒▒▒   ▒▌██▐██▒▒▌▒
          █████     ▒▌ ▒▐█▒▐  ▒▒█▒▐▄▒▒  ▌ ▒▒████▌       ▒████▀▒▒▒▌▒
          ████▐     ▒▌     ▐█  ▒▒▒▒▐    █ ▒▒██▌▌      ▒▌ ▌▒▒▒▒▒▌
           ██ ▐▐█   ▒█             █      ▒▒██▌▌       ▌ ▌▒▒   █ """

string = string \
    .replace("▒",bloodred+"▒"+reset) \
    .replace("█", purple+"█"+reset) \
    .replace("▀", purple+"▀"+reset) \
    .replace("▐", bloodred+"▐"+reset) \
    .replace("▄", purple+"▄"+reset) \
    .replace("▌", bloodred+"▌"+reset) \
    
print(string)
```

This would look roughly like this: [image: Result]

Comment: Holy shit that looks horrible, but it doesn't matter ill choose a different color off of what was provided thanks I was on this for 2 hours!!

Comment: Same thougt, but it is what you asked for xD. Happy to help though

Answer (score 1):

you can use termcolor and pyfiglet. to  install:

```
pip install termcolor
pip install pyfiglet
```

Sample code:

```
from termcolor import colored
from pyfiglet import Figlet

f=Figlet(font='standard')
print(colored(f.renderText('GOOD'),'green'))

f=Figlet(font='digital')
print(colored(f.renderText('BAD'),'red'))

f=Figlet(font='banner3-D')
print(colored(f.renderText('OK'),'blue'))

f=Figlet(font='bubble')
print(colored(f.renderText('COOL'),'magenta'))
```

Output:

[image: output]

for more fonts you can visit: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-ascii-art-using-pyfiglet-module/

details for termcolor: https://pypi.org/project/termcolor/

for more colored you can use colored module: https://pypi.org/project/colored/

Answer (score 1):

to exactly solve your issue. below is the code:

```
from colored import fg, bg, attr
import os
red = fg('red_1')
bloodred = fg('dark_red_2')
purple = fg('purple_1a')
white = fg('white')
green = fg('light_green')
blue = fg('blue')
grey = fg('grey_54')
yellow = fg('yellow')
reset = attr('reset')
os.system('clear')
print("""
                                ▒▒▒▒                       ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒
    ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒█▒               ▒▒▒█▒▒                     ▒▒▒▒▒██▌▒▒▒▒
▒▒▒▒▒█████▒▒▒▒▒▒          ▒▒▒████▒▒                   ▒▒▒▒█▒▒█▄ ▒▒▒▒
▒ ▒▒████▒█████▒▄▒         ▒▒███▒█▒██▒▒▒▒     ▒▄▒▒    ▒▒▒▐▒▒██████▄▒▒
▒▒▒███████▒▒████▒▒        ▒████▒▒█▒███ ▒   ▒▒▒██▒▒▒   ▒▒▐███▌▐████▌▒▒▒
▒▒▒▒▄▒▒██▀▀▀▀▀█▒███▒▒       ▒███▒▒▒▒▒▒███▒▒  ▒▒████▒▒▒   ▒▒███ ▒ ████ ▒▒▒
▒▒▐█▒█▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▀███▌▒▒      ▒█▌▌▒▒▄▄▒▒▐█▒▒▒ ▒▒██▀▒███▒▒   ▒███▒▒▒ ▒███▒▒▒▒
▒▒▒████▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒█▒▒▒      ▒███▒████▒███▒▒  ██▌▒▒▒███▒▒  ▒██▌▒▒▒▒▒████▒▒▒▒
▒ ▒███▒▒▒▒     ▒▒▒▒▒▒       ██▒██████▒▒██▒▒  ███▒▒▒▒██▒▒  ▒██▌▒▒▒▒▒ ███▄▒▒
▒ ▒█▒█▒▒▒                   ██▒▒██ ██▒███▒▒  ▐██ ▒▒▒███▒  ▒▐█▌▒▒▒▒▒ ▐████▒▒▒
▒▒▒███▒▒▒                  ▒███▒██ ██▒█▒█▒▒  ▄██▒▒▒▒▐███▒ ▒██▌▒▒▒▒▒▒▐█▄███▒▒
▒▒█▒█▌▒▒            ▒▒▒   ▒███▒██ ██▒▒██▒▒ ▐██▌▒▒▒▒▒███▒▒▒██▌▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒██▄██▒▒▒
▒███▒▒       ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒████▒▒███▒██ ██ ▒██▒▒  ██▌▒  ▒▒████▒▒██▌ ▒▒▒▒▒ ▒███████▒
▒██▒▒      ▒▒▒▒▒▒████▒███▒██▌▒██ ██▒▒██▒▒▒ ██▌▒   ▒▒███▒▒▐██ ▒▒▒█▒▒▒▒ ██▒██▌
▒███▒▒     ▒▒█████▒█▒▀▀██▒██ ███ ██▒▒██▒▒▒▒▐█▌▒ ▒█▌ ▐██▌▒▐██▌ ▒█▒█▒▒▒ █▌▒██▒
▒█▒█▌▒    ▒▒█▒█▒▒▀███▒▒▌▀███▒▒██ ██▒▒██▒▒▒▒██▌▒ ███▌▒██▌▒██▒▌ ▒██▀▒▒▒▄████▒▒
▒██▒█▒   ▒▒█▒█▒▒▒▒▒███▒▌▒▒██▒▒██  █▒▒██▒▒▒▒██▌▒ ███▌▒██▌▒███▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ █████▒▒▒
▒▒█▒█▒▒ ▒▒█▒█▒▒   ▒█▒█▒▌  ██▒▒█████▒▒█▐▒▒▐███▌▒ ▒█ ▒▒██▌▐███ ▒▒█▒▒ █████▒▒▒
▒▒████▒▒ ███▒▒    ▒███▒▌  ██▒▒ ████▒███▒▒▐███▌▒   ▒▒███▒▐██▌▒▒▒▒▒ ▐████▒▒
▒▒██▒██▒▒█▒▒▒   ▒▒████▒▌ ▒██▒▒▒██▌▒██▒▀▌▒▒███▌▒▒ ▒▒███▒▌▐██▌▒▒▒▒ ████▒▒▒
▒▒█▒███▒▒▀▒   ▒▒█████▌▒█ ▒▐█▒▒▒▒▒▒▒█▒█▒▌▒▒ ██▌▒▒▒▒▒███▒▌▒█▒▌▒▒▒ ▄███▒▒▒
▒▒███▒█▒▒▒▒  ▒▒██▒███▒▒▐ ▒▒███▒▒▒▒▄█▒█▒▌▒▒▒▐██▒▒▄▄██▌▒▒▌▒██▒▒▒▒████ ▒▒
▒▒█▒█████▄▒▒▒▒███▒██▒▒ ▐ ▒▐████▒▒█▒██▒▒▌▒▒▒███▒█████▒▒▒▌▒██ ▒ ████▌▒▒
▒▒▒▒██▒█▒███▄█████▒▒▌ ▒▐ ▒▐▐█████▒▒██▒▒▌▒▒▒▐██▐███▒ ▒▒ ▌▒█  █████▀▒▒
    ▒▒▒▀████▒███▌▒▒▒▌ ▒▐ ▒▐▒██▒█████▒▒▒▌ ▒▒▒█▌███▒▒▒  ▒▌▒███████▒
    ▒▒▒██▄████▒▒ ▒▌ ▒▐ ▒▐▒▒▒███▐▒▒▒▒ ▌ ▒▒█████▒▒▒   ▒▌██▐██▒▒▌▒
        █████     ▒▌ ▒▐█▒▐  ▒▒█▒▐▄▒▒  ▌ ▒▒████▌       ▒████▀▒▒▒▌▒
        ████▐     ▒▌     ▐█  ▒▒▒▒▐    █ ▒▒██▌▌      ▒▌ ▌▒▒▒▒▒▌
        ██ ▐▐█   ▒█             █      ▒▒██▌▌       ▌ ▌▒▒   █ """.replace('█', purple + '█' + reset) \
                                                                    .replace('▒', bloodred + '▒' + reset))
print(white,"                     .:[",green,"/\"]Created By Antichrist [/\]:.")
print(white,"                            [+] Login Page [+]")
```

Output:

[image: output]

Comment: There are some more charakters aside from `▒` and `█` that need coloring. Otherwise they stay white.